# CGAL::Surface_mesh_parameterization: write the vertices to off in the original order

Tags: c++, file-io, mesh, cgal, parameterization

I am trying to modify `CGAL-4.13/examples/Surface_mesh_parameterization/lscm.cpp` so that the order of the vertices in the resulting off file is the same as in the input file.

### Update: Example

Take a file `input.off` with the following simple content:

```
OFF
4 2 0
-0.9310345 0.4333333 0 
-1 0.4333333 0 
-0.9310345 0.5 0 
-1 0.5 0 
3 1 0 2
3 2 3 1
```

When I call the standard `lscm` from CGAL with

```
/path/to/CGAL-4.13-build/examples/Surface_mesh_parameterization/lscm input.off
```

I obtain `coords.off` containing

```
OFF
4 2 0
-1 0.5 0
-0.931034 0.5 0
-0.931034 0.433333 0
-1 0.433333 0
3 3 2 1
3 1 0 3
```

and `uvmap.off` with

```
OFF
4 2 0
-0.0166567 0.982769 0
1 1 0
1.01666 0.0172311 0
0 0 0
3 3 2 1
3 1 0 3
```

The files `coords.off` and `uvmap.off` contain the vertices and their parameter pairs in the same order (which is *different* from that in `input.off`). Instead, I would like the parameters in `uvmap.off` to be in the order corresponding to `input.off`. In particular, I want `uvmap.off` to look like this:

```
OFF
4 2 0
1.01666 0.0172311 0
0 0 0
1 1 0
-0.0166567 0.982769 0
3 1 0 2
3 2 3 1
```

Basically, this renders `coords.off` redundant, as I can use `input.off` in its role.

### Effort at a solution

From what I understand, this might be possible to achieve by calling `output_uvmap_to_off(...)` with 6 parameters instead of 4 (both versions can be found in `CGAL-4.13/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/IO/File_off.h`). As one of these parameters is a `VertexIndexMap`, I should probably also use

```
CGAL::Surface_mesh_parameterization::LSCM_parameterizer_3< TriangleMesh_, BorderParameterizer_, SolverTraits_ >::parameterize(...)
```

instead of

```
CGAL::Surface_mesh_parameterization::parameterize(...)
```

used in the example.

Here is a minimal (not really working) example. It is derived from `lscm.cpp` but I threw away a lot of things to remain concise.

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/Seam_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/IO/File_off.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/parameterize.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/Two_vertices_parameterizer_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_parameterization/LSCM_parameterizer_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/measure.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>      Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                     Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                     Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> SurfaceMesh;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SurfaceMesh>::edge_descriptor SM_edge_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SurfaceMesh>::halfedge_descriptor SM_halfedge_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SurfaceMesh>::vertex_descriptor SM_vertex_descriptor;
typedef SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, Point_2> UV_pmap;
typedef SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SM_edge_descriptor, bool> Seam_edge_pmap;
typedef SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SM_vertex_descriptor, bool> Seam_vertex_pmap;
typedef CGAL::Seam_mesh<SurfaceMesh, Seam_edge_pmap, Seam_vertex_pmap> Mesh;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::halfedge_descriptor halfedge_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::face_descriptor face_descriptor;

namespace SMP = CGAL::Surface_mesh_parameterization;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::ifstream in_mesh((argc>1) ? argv[1] : "data/lion.off");
  if(!in_mesh){
    std::cerr << "Error: problem loading the input data" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  SurfaceMesh sm;
  in_mesh >> sm;

  Seam_edge_pmap seam_edge_pm = sm.add_property_map<SM_edge_descriptor, bool>("e:on_seam", false).first;
  Seam_vertex_pmap seam_vertex_pm = sm.add_property_map<SM_vertex_descriptor, bool>("v:on_seam", false).first;

  Mesh mesh(sm, seam_edge_pm, seam_vertex_pm);
  UV_pmap uv_pm = sm.add_property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, Point_2>("h:uv").first;

  halfedge_descriptor bhd = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border(mesh, CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::parameters::all_default()).first;

  typedef SMP::Two_vertices_parameterizer_3<Mesh>                Border_parameterizer;
  typedef SMP::LSCM_parameterizer_3<Mesh, Border_parameterizer>  Parameterizer;

  // Here's where the big changes start.
  SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, int> vimap = sm.add_property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, int>("h:vi").first;
  SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, bool> vpmap = sm.add_property_map<SM_halfedge_descriptor, bool>("h:vp").first;
  Parameterizer parameterizer;
  parameterizer.parameterize(mesh, bhd, uv_pm, vimap, vpmap);

  const char* uvmap_file = "uvmap.off";
  std::ofstream uvmap_out(uvmap_file);
  SMP::IO::output_uvmap_to_off(mesh,sm.vertices(),sm.faces(),uv_pm,vimap,uvmap_out);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This does not compile, complaining about a required conversion on line 131 in File_off.h.

### Actual questions

- Is `vimap` initialized correctly?
- Is this the reasonable direction towards my goal of writing the vertices in the same order?
- If yes, how do I pass the correct arguments to `output_uvmap_to_off(...)`? For instance, it asks for a `VertexContainer` and I provide a `Vertex_range` (hence the compilation error, I suppose). Shall I just collect the vertices as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809669/how-to-get-the-vertices-and-the-faces-of-a-polygon-mesh-with-cgal) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521720/cgal-read-vertices-and-triangles-from-mesh) or is there a more elegant way?
- If no, what is the right course of action?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because looking at the code of the function `output_uvmap_to_off()` that is taking a mesh (and not the vertex range), the vertices are precisely in the same order as in the mesh (l. 125 in the file for me). Why do you think the order is not preserved?

Comment: @sloriot I have added an example to explain better what I get and what I would like to get instead.

Comment: Is there anything I could do to improve chances of getting an answer? Shall I explain some parts more precisely? Or is it just bad luck and no-one knows?

Comment: It seems that this [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/2994) should answer your question.

Comment: @sloriot Indeed, it does, thank you very much. I had to use `Polyhedron_3` instead of `Surface_mesh` but that is fine. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/2994) answers this question.